# Why do some comments and responses have timestamps earlier than those for the corresponding question?

Tags: support

I just noticed that [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30093/is-user-experience-design-uxd-equal-to-user-centered-design-ucd) (asked an hour ago on December 5) appears to have a comment on it from October 24th.  There's also a response from "October 24th."  It looks like the system may be mis-parsing 12/4 as 10/24?  Or, more likely, the server's system clock is off.  Is this the right place to report a bug like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug actually; if you check the [revisions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/30093/revisions) I actually merged that question. Apparently there isn't a visual indicator of this outside the revision history, which is almost bug-worthy itself really. That moves over all the answers (the October one) and apparently comments, which I didn't expect. Though personally I find the comment applies to the new question as well...

The [merged question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28244/differentiate-user-centered-design-and-user-experience-design) was an older, closed post that's essentially the same post, just not asked as well. I wasn't about to close the new post as a duplicate of a closed question, and since both had answers, merging seemed like the best solution.